# XPath test for node exists and contains a number

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, domxpath, xquery-sql

I need a condition in XPath or XQuery to determine if a `product` has the node `Id` and if that node has a number.

```
<ns34:Product>
  <ns34:Id>100</ns34:Id>
</ns34:Product>
<ns34:Product>
  <ns34:Id>104</ns34:Id>
</ns34:Product>
```

Comment: Please post your tried code with complete input XML and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming** that your actual XML is well-formed with a single root element...

**And** that you've properly registered a namespace for the `ns34` prefix...

**And** that you've somehow selected the desired `Product` (no criteria was given in your question) and bound it to variable, `$p`...

This expression will test whether `$p` has a `ns34:Id` child element:

```
$p/ns34:Id
```

And this expression will test whether it is a number:

```
number($p/ns34:Id) = $p/ns34:Id
```

And this expression will select those products that have an `ns34:Id` child element that is a number:

```
//ns34:Product[number(ns34:Id) = ns34:Id]
```